# OTA update for ESP32 in Arduino ide from a different nework

Tags: esp32, ota

I am trying to use the OTA to update my code in esp32. I have used Web updater so far and it has worked perfectly. But I want to update the code even when I am not connected in the same network with my esp32. Say, the esp32 have an ip from my phone Ap : 192.168.1.43 and I am connected in a different one say, 192.168.25.12 As both of them are class C ip having default subnet mask then we are in different network.

I have found this following question 
[OTA updating the ESP32 from a separate server](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66181/ota-updating-the-esp32-from-a-separate-server)
It did not clarify things to me.

Comment: I know nothing about OTA updates, but isn't this just a routing problem between the networks?

Comment: then it is better to download he update with the HTTPUpdate library

Comment: there's 3 different OTA routines i've seen, (IDE, self-hosted web, WWW) maybe more exist. the one where your bin files are on a web server should work across different nets, as long as they have internet.

Comment: dandavis by self hosted do you mean the bin file and esp32 are connected in the same network?? And by www, in other networks??